# Не распознает команду в VS на C#

Tags: c#

После прошлого вопроса в этой программе:

```
using System;

namespace HelloCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, C#!");
        }
    }
}
```

Появляется это:

```
'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Все расширения установлены,да и в отладке ничего не пишет, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: По ссылке видно что и как https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ9nCLJg4hQ. Здесь расшифровывать все шаги вряд ли кто будет, да и зачем. если ищется в поисковике на раз-два.